# Is it possible to build a Chrome extension using Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to build a Chrome extension using Java *rather than* JavaScript? (I use Java SE in Eclipse IDE.)

Comment: Check [this](http://blog.tomtasche.at/2011/08/chromegwt-building-chrome-extensions.html) blog.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Chrome extensions must run JavaScript. You can however use [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) to compile Java to JavaScript.

Comment: You can also write apps in C and C++ using [Chrome Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/overview)

Comment: And you can write Chrome extensions in Kotlin. See [Medium](https://medium.com/@rivasdiaz/writing-a-chrome-extension-in-kotlin-part-1-e013d431b63f).

Answer (score 11):

There is an open source project (that I have not used though) called [gwt-chrome](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-chrome/) that aims to do just that. It lacks a good documentation though.