# Java in chrome extension

Tags: java, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension. Since I prefer java and have to use some of java libraries to accomplish the task. I am thinking of creating a servlet on apache tomcat. Then I can do a post request on the servlet from extension. Remember everything needs to be on client side. Is there any better approach to do this (Use java in chrome extension).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
You don't have to make a servlet. I'd rather just listen on a TCP port with a [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and listen for POST requests. This is what JDonwloader does with it's [Click'n'Load 2](http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/glossary/cnl2).

**Option 2:** You could use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) as another approach, which would be better because your jar file would just be running when it's needed.

**Option 3:** This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735906/5409369) of the question [@Haibara Ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467592/java-in-chrome-extension#comment60551986_36467592) linked in his comment suggests using the [GWT SDK](http://www.gwtproject.org/). On it's site it states that the performance should be good, but I don't have any experience with it. But reading through its documentation, it seems good for advanced applications.

**Conclusion:** In your case I would use Option 1 because Native Messaging is a bit more complicated and you'll have less problems what concerns the JavaScript side. But when you want to accomplish more advanced things, Native Messaging is the proper way because then you can pass messages by calling `System.out.println()` and read data from the extension by calling `System.in.readLine()`. If you want to take a deeper look at this kind of programs I'd use Option 3.